# mouseenter bubbling when mousehover multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to prevent bubbling or "out of control" when user hover(`mouseenter`) multiple times . When user hover i'm using slideDown and slideUp for mouseleave and delay i set 250. I can only fix this if delay i set to 1 ms. Below is my script :

```
$("#nav li").mouseenter(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (!is_opened) {
        var left = $(this).position().left;
        $(this).children('div').css('left', '-' + left + 'px');
        $(this).children('div').slideDown(delay, function () {
            // Animation complete.
            is_opened = true;
        });
    }

    return false;
});

$("#nav li").mouseleave(function () {

    if (is_opened) {
        $(this).children('div').slideUp(delay, function () {
            // Animation complete.
            is_opened = false;
        });
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (is_opened) {
                $('#nav li:first-child').children('div').slideUp(delay, function () {
                    // Animation complete.
                    is_opened = false;
                });

            }
        }, 1000);

    }
    return false;
});
```

You can check my JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ruslyrossi/SD4Tp/4/)

**Reproduce a Problem**

- Hover Catalogue multiple times and stop hover(but point your cursor at Catalogue), you will see the dropdown will hide but actually it should slide down.

Comment: do you need the is_opened flag? http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/SD4Tp/5/

Comment: or a bit better handling of the stop: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/SD4Tp/10/

Comment: have added the answer, glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is caused by the `is_opened` flag and then the animation being run along side changing the `left` css property

If you change your mouse enter and leave js to the following

```
   $("#nav li").each(function() {
        //cache vars for better performance
        var li = $(this);
        var left = $(this).position().left;
        var divs = li.children('div');

        //change div left first so it only changes once
        divs.css('left', '-' + left + 'px');

        //do mouse enter and leave stuff
        li.mouseenter(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            divs.stop(true, true).slideDown(delay);
        });

        li.mouseleave(function () {
            divs.stop().slideUp(delay);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

it should work: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/SD4Tp/12/)